# SET DEFAULT Never get fired

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having difficulty in finding the issue in my table definitions. I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
Customer_ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Customer_Pref char(20) default 'PPPP',
Foreign key (Customer_Pref) references Pref  ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
)

CREATE TABLE Pref
(
 PrefID char(20) primary key,
PrefName char(100),
);
```

I have a tuple in Customer table with Pref 'P3'. P3 exist in my Pref table.

When I delete PrefID =3 from Preference table, then DEFAULT constraint on  CUSTOMER table never get fired.

It shows me the following error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK__CUSTOMER__Custom__1209AD79". The conflict occurred in database
>   "aaa", table "dbo.Pref", column 'PrefID'.

Please help. I have spent so much time on this without any luck.

Comment: Is 'PPPP' in the pref table? Because if it isn't, the issue is that the foreign key needs to reference a value.

Comment: Works for me: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/72245/2)

Comment: Thanks! Why 'PPPP' need to be in PREF table. 'PPPP' is the default value for customer_Pref in the Customer table.  My understanding of SET DEFAULT is that 'When the tiple will be deleted from the main table then in the referenced table, the value should be changed to the default one".

Comment: The foreign key means the value _must_ exist in the pref table. If you make your default something that does not exist in the pref table, then you'll get a constraint violation.